# how remove item with attrib repeat rethinkdb

Tags: reduce, rethinkdb

i have a problem. I have a query in rethinkdb but show a problem when i try remove items that have one attrib repeat.

## data table

```
[
    {
        codeQR: '100001597182620700',
        numid: '1000081',
        user: 'a1d0c8d0-7305-43b1-8b4d-d9a6274d76f5'
    },
    {
        codeQR: '100001597182749578',
        numid: '1000082',
        user: 'a1d0c8d0-7305-43b1-8b4d-d9a6274d76f5'
    },
    {
        codeQR: '100001597185279006',
        numid: '1000082',
        user: 'a1d0c8d0-7305-43b1-8b4d-d9a6274d76f5'
    },
    {
        codeQR: '100001597183951080',
        numid: '1000082',
        user: 'a1d0c8d0-7305-43b1-8b4d-d9a6274d76f5'
    },
    {
        codeQR: '100001597183951216',
        numid: '1000083',
        user: 'a1d0c8d0-7305-43b1-8b4d-d9a6274d76f5'
    },
    {
        codeQR: '100001597185279182',
        numid: '1000083',
        user: 'a1d0c8d0-7305-43b1-8b4d-d9a6274d76f5'
    },
    {
        codeQR: '100001597182864764',
        numid: '1000083',
        user: 'a1d0c8d0-7305-43b1-8b4d-d9a6274d76f5'
    },
    {
        codeQR: '100001597185307862',
        numid: '1000084',
        user: 'a1d0c8d0-7305-43b1-8b4d-d9a6274d76f5'
    },
    {
        codeQR: '100001597183974288',
        numid: '1000084',
        user: 'a1d0c8d0-7305-43b1-8b4d-d9a6274d76f5'
    },
    {
        codeQR: '100001597183002590',
        numid: '1000084',
        user: 'a1d0c8d0-7305-43b1-8b4d-d9a6274d76f5'
    }
]
```

#### query with rethinkdb

```
r.db('myDb').table('userSearchData')
.filter(querys=>
    querys('numid').gt('1000080')
    .and(
        querys('numid').lt(String('1000085'))
    )
)
.limit(5)
```

and this query show it:

```
[
    {
        codeQR: '100001597182620700',
        numid: '1000081',
        user: 'a1d0c8d0-7305-43b1-8b4d-d9a6274d76f5'
    },
    {
        codeQR: '100001597182749578',
        numid: '1000082',
        user: 'a1d0c8d0-7305-43b1-8b4d-d9a6274d76f5'
    },
    {
        codeQR: '100001597185279006',
        numid: '1000082',
        user: 'a1d0c8d0-7305-43b1-8b4d-d9a6274d76f5'
    },
    {
        codeQR: '100001597183951080',
        numid: '1000082',
        user: 'a1d0c8d0-7305-43b1-8b4d-d9a6274d76f5'
    },
    {
        codeQR: '100001597183951216',
        numid: '1000083',
        user: 'a1d0c8d0-7305-43b1-8b4d-d9a6274d76f5'
    }
]
```

so, the problem is because if you see, the array has a items with attrib **numid** and i want that only it shows one item of same **numid**. I resolved it with **reduce() javascript** function like that

```
let datas=resultQuery.reduce((arry, val)=>{
    if(arry.length){
        if(!arry.some(val2=>val2.numid===val.numid)){
            arry.push(val)
        }
    }else
        arry.push(val)
    return arry
}, [])
console.log(datas, 'FT array filter', __filename)
```

#### and final result is:

```
[
    {
        codeQR: '100001597182620700',
        numid: '1000081',
        user: 'a1d0c8d0-7305-43b1-8b4d-d9a6274d76f5'
    },
    {
        codeQR: '100001597182749578',
        numid: '1000082',
        user: 'a1d0c8d0-7305-43b1-8b4d-d9a6274d76f5'
    },
    {
        codeQR: '100001597183951216',
        numid: '1000083',
        user: 'a1d0c8d0-7305-43b1-8b4d-d9a6274d76f5'
    }
]
```

But only has 3 item of 5 that i ordered

#### Img shows than me want with that rethinkdb

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `group` to group your data by matching `numid`. Then select the first entries in those group. I am not sure what the desired selection should be, but you can implement any criteria in the map function.

```
r.db('myDb').table('userSearchData')
.filter(querys=>
    querys('numid').gt('1000080')
    .and(
        querys('numid').lt(String('1000085'))
    )
)
.group("numid")
.ungroup()
.map(r.row("reduction")(0))
.limit(5)
```

Grouping the data will result in buckets as follows:

```
[
    {
        "group": "1000081",
        "reduction": [
            {
                "codeQR": "100001597182620700",
                "numid": "1000081",
                "user": "a1d0c8d0-7305-43b1-8b4d-d9a6274d76f5"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "group": "1000082",
        "reduction": [
            {
                "codeQR": "100001597183951080",
                "numid": "1000082",
                "user": "a1d0c8d0-7305-43b1-8b4d-d9a6274d76f5"
            },
            {
                "codeQR": "100001597182749578",
                "numid": "1000082",
                "user": "a1d0c8d0-7305-43b1-8b4d-d9a6274d76f5"
            },
            {
                "codeQR": "100001597185279006",
                "numid": "1000082",
                "user": "a1d0c8d0-7305-43b1-8b4d-d9a6274d76f5"
            }
        ]
    } 
//....
]
```

Then you will have to use the `ungroup` function to continue adding methods to the query. And with `map()` you select the first element of each reduction.

then your result is:

```
[
    {
        "codeQR": "100001597182620700",
        "numid": "1000081",
        "user": "a1d0c8d0-7305-43b1-8b4d-d9a6274d76f5"
    },
    {
        "codeQR": "100001597183951080",
        "numid": "1000082",
        "user": "a1d0c8d0-7305-43b1-8b4d-d9a6274d76f5"
    },
    {
        "codeQR": "100001597185279182",
        "numid": "1000083",
        "user": "a1d0c8d0-7305-43b1-8b4d-d9a6274d76f5"
    },
    {
        "codeQR": "100001597183974288",
        "numid": "1000084",
        "user": "a1d0c8d0-7305-43b1-8b4d-d9a6274d76f5"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The result that you are getting is correct. I dont know exactly what your expectations are:

```
let datas=resultQuery.reduce((arry, val)=>{
    if(arry.length){
        if(!arry.some(val2=>val2.numid===val.numid)){
            arry.push(val)
        }
    }else
        arry.push(val)
    return arry
}, [])
console.log(datas, 'FT array filter', __filename)
```

1. at the first item arry.length is false therefore you just add the item
2. second item you check if numid is not yet existing -> add item
3. numid already exist -> skip
4. numid already exist -> skip
5. numid new -> add item

Comment: with reduce() of javascript i don't work directly in rethinkdb, i work with the result, for example on this case i want get 4 items but i only could get 3, because rethinkdb give me one array with 5 items, but some items of this array are repeat, i want that rethinkdb give me 4 items without repeat in the array.

I put an img in my post, for show more datails about of my problem

Comment: i see, and how about using `.distinct()` , right before the `.limit(5)`?

Comment: distinc only works when all array have the same content, but on this items  the codeQR aren't similar, for this cause distinct() doesn't make nothing